# Circular makemigrations/migrate issue: No migrations to apply

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have this model on my Django 1.8 app deployed to Heroku. When I run 'makemigrations' I get:

```
Migrations for 'account':
  0002_auto_20150412_1337.py:
    - Alter field email on emailaddress
Migrations for 'socialaccount':
  0002_auto_20150412_1337.py:
    - Alter field provider on socialaccount
    - Alter field provider on socialapp
```

But when I run 'migrate' I get this:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, allauth, staticfiles, facebook
  Apply all migrations: accounts, sites, auth, socialaccount, account, admin, contenttypes, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I have encountered this before when building a similar app for 1.6, then I solved it by faking the first migration. That wont seem to work this time around though.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver
from appname import settings

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    age = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, default ="")
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, default ="")
    updated_profile = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    rating_access = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    seen_introduction = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s profile. Age: %s, Location: %s" % (self.user.username, self.age, self.location)

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def new_user_signup(sender, **kwargs):
    p = UserProfile(user = kwargs['user'])
    p.save()
```

Comment: Can you check if both migration files are actually created and readable by Django?

Comment: App is deployed on Heroku (have updated question to reflect this) where I don't have control over the permissions

Comment: Surely you can see if the files are there and what the permissions are? Did you create the migrations locally and push them to Heroku? I believe I've seen people having trouble when they tried to create the migrations on Heroku.

Comment: @knbk I am getting the same errors. Multiple migration files are generated like this 

Migrations for 'socialaccount':
  0013_auto_20160513_1224.py:
    - Alter field provider on socialaccount
    - Alter field provider on socialapp
Can you please help??